Join on 3 Tables for all non-matching columns in second and third Table(with some conditions) to be returned
Table inward



session_id
beneficiary_account_no
amount
transaction_date




2
46027846841
200
2024-06-04 00:00:21


3
46091218383
199
2024-06-05 00:00:22


6
46087226332
122
2024-06-06 00:00:23


9
46053373774
34
2024-06-07 00:00:24


5
46073747321
54
2024-06-08 00:00:25



Table wallet



session_id
to_account_no
amount
time




2
46027846841
200
2024-06-04 00:00:22


3
46091218383
199
2024-06-05 00:00:23



Table pending_wallet



session_id
amount
to_account_no
created_date
status




2
200
46027846841
2024-06-04 00:00:21
00


3
199
46091218383
2024-06-05 00:00:22
00


6
122
46087226332
2024-06-06 00:00:23
00


9
34
46053373774
2024-06-07 00:00:24
09


5
54
46073747321
2024-06-08 00:00:25
02



Sincere apologies if this has been treated in the past. I cannot seem to find it on Stackoverflow.
I want my SQL code to return session_id 6. Reasons being that it is on "inward" Table but not on "Wallet" Table and also on "pending_wallet" Table with status as '00'. '00' means successful in this context.
At the end. The intention is to make sure all transactions in "inward" Table makes it to "wallet" Table as long as it is
not on "pending_wallet" Table or it is on "pending_wallet" Table but with status set to '00'.  All transactions on inward table should eventually make it to wallet table.
SQL I have is:
SELECT session_id FROM INWARD WHERE beneficiary_account_no LIKE '460%'
AND transaction_date > '2024-06-06' AND transaction_date < '2024-06-08 00:00:30'
from inward
left join pending_wallet on inward.SESSION_ID =  pending_wallet.session_id
left join wallet on inward.SESSION_ID =  wallet.session_id
where pending_wallet.SESSION_ID is NULL AND pending_wallet.session_id = '00';


Please read How to make an example and Why not upload images and then improve your question.

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, especially #5 and #3.

Thank you Akina and Jonas. I will edit the post.

The structure of your SQL is incorrect. Order of keywords does not follow the rules. See the SQL below. Friendly advice is to structure your code formating it consistently and use aliases for better readability and maintenability...
WITH    -- S a m p l e    D a t a :
    inward (session_id, beneficiary_account_no, amount, transaction_date) AS
      ( Select 2, 46027846841, 200,  '2024-06-04 00:00:21' Union All 
        Select 3, 46091218383, 199,  '2024-06-05 00:00:22' Union All 
        Select 6, 46087226332, 122,  '2024-06-06 00:00:23' Union All 
        Select 9, 46053373774,  34,  '2024-06-07 00:00:24' Union All 
        Select 5, 46073747321,  54,  '2024-06-08 00:00:25' 
      ), 
    wallet (session_id, to_account_no, amount, time) AS
      ( Select 2, 46027846841, 200,  '2024-06-04 00:00:22' Union All 
        Select 3, 46091218383, 199,  '2024-06-05 00:00:23'
      ), 
    pending_wallet (session_id, to_account_no, amount, created_date, status) AS
      ( Select 2, 46027846841, 200,  '2024-06-04 00:00:21', '00' Union All 
        Select 3, 46091218383, 199,  '2024-06-05 00:00:22', '00' Union All 
        Select 6, 46087226332, 122,  '2024-06-06 00:00:23', '00' Union All 
        Select 9, 46053373774,  34,  '2024-06-07 00:00:24', '09' Union All 
        Select 5, 46073747321,  54,  '2024-06-08 00:00:25', '02'
      )

note that status != '00' is in Left Join's ON clause and wallet's and pending_wallet's session_id is in Where clause (Is Null)
--    S Q L :
Select      i.session_id, i.beneficiary_account_no, i.amount, i.transaction_date
From        inward i
Left Join   wallet w ON(w.session_id = i.session_id)
Left Join   pending_wallet pw ON(pw.session_id = i.session_id And 
                                 pw.status != '00')
Where       w.session_id Is Null And 
            pw.session_id Is Null And
            i.beneficiary_account_no LIKE '460%' And 
            i.transaction_date > '2024-06-06' And 
            i.transaction_date < '2024-06-08 00:00:30'

/*    R e s u l t :
session_id  beneficiary_account_no  amount  transaction_date
----------  ----------------------  ------  ----------------------
         6             46087226332     122  2024-06-06 00:00:23  */


Thank you d r. Please let me try this and revert for a vote.

Thank you d r. This worked and returned the expected resultsets. I want just session_ids returned so I am going to indicate that in my java codebase. I really appreciate.
